# LaTeX complains about a long url, how to fix the issue?

Tags: urls, overfull

I would like to write my essay such that it won't complain about too long Internet addressess. How can I fix this code that contains the settings for my essay?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \title{\textbf{Gummi 0.8.0}}
    \author{me}
    \date{}
    
    \addtolength{\topmargin}{-3cm}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{3cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[%
    left=3cm,%
    right=3cm,%
    top=2.5cm,%3
    bottom=2.5cm,%
    headheight=33pt,%
]{geometry}%
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{\pagemark}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\footheight}{17.99445pt}
\topskip0pt
\vspace*{\fill}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
smth

$\,$

Me
\end{center}
\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
\vspace{10em}

\end{center}

{\raggedleft some data
}

\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\onehalfspacing
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\noindent \section{Johdanto} Olen
\section{Lähteet}
\begin{itemize}

    \item[] Kruger, J., Dunning, D. \textit{Unskilled and unaware of it: how difficulties in recognizing one's own incompetence lead to inflated self-assessments} (30.11.1999).\url{https://lesn.appstate.edu/olson/Protected/Articles/pdf%20docs/
    
    Kruger%20&%20Dunning%20(1999)%20%5BClueless%20article%5D.pdf}
    
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's a warning, isn't it? So it does compile but may appear a bit strange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to fix the issue?

If you load the [xurl](https://ctan.org/pkg/xurl) package, line breaks can occur anywhere in the argument of `\url`. (Usually, but not necessarily, the arguments of `\url` directives are URL strings.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item[] Kruger, J., Dunning, D. 
\textit{Unskilled and unaware of it: How difficulties in recognizing one's own incompetence lead to inflated self-assessments} (30.11.1999). 
\url{https://lesn.appstate.edu/olson/Protected/Articles/pdf%20docs/Kruger%20&%20Dunning%20(1999)%20%5BClueless%20article%5D.pdf}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```